# Problem with abstract Page in Release build

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

#### The situation

I have made an abstract `Page` for my UWP app: `TestPage`. This page contains some abstract items, in this simplified case just a `string`.

> MVCE can be found [here](https://github.com/Leander-van-Boven/Abstract-UWP-Page)

C# code:

```cs
public abstract partial class TestPage : Page
{
    public abstract string AbstractName { get; }

    public TestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="UWP_Test.TestPage"
    ...
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                   Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" 
                   Text="{x:Bind AbstractName}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I then have made two derived pages, or rather classes:

```cs
public sealed class TestPage1 : TestPage
{
    public override string AbstractName => "TestPage1";
}
public sealed class TestPage2 : TestPage
{
    public override string AbstractName => "TestPage2";
}
```

#### The problem

If I now try to navigate a `Frame` to either `TestPage1` or `TestPage2`, this will work in a **DEBUG** build, but fail in a **RELEASE** build (*System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory.'*).
This is regardless of whether *optimize code* or *.net native toolchain* are enabled or disabled.

For my actual UWP app I would like to be able to use aforementioned principle to quickly make very similar pages that differ in a few aspects such as `ItemTemplates`, Viewmodels, etc.

I'd appreciate any leads that could either make this work in a release build or how to solve this (without creating a separate XAML file for each derived page, I already use this somewhere else and that is working in release).

Comment: Why AbstractName in base class is protected internal?

Comment: I've tried some during testing, all failed during release build. I've made it all coherent now in the post

Comment: `I already use this somewhere else and that is working in release` Do you mean the code works in another UWP app?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Not like this, so what I want is 1 XAML + class for the actual UI page and then multiple derived classes that specify some features of this UI such as itemtemplates/viewmodels/etc. What I do have working is multiple XAML files e.g. `TestPage1` and `TestPage2` each have a XAML file and then `TestPage` having some generic eventhandlers/dealing with `OnNavigatedTo`, etc. In this case `TestPage` does **not** have a XAML file. You get what I mean?

Comment: Could you please share an [mvce] on GitHub or Onedrive with me? This could help to check the reason.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Thanks for answering, an mvce can be found here: https://github.com/Leander-van-Boven/Abstract-UWP-Page I have tried to explain what is going wrong in the page summaries. Try to run the App in both Debug and Release build and click both `NavigationViewItem` and you should be able to observe my problem.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Did you manage to take a look at this?

Comment: Haven't done much XAML since WPF but I think there's a problem with class definition in your XAML code.

Here: x:Class="UWP_Test.TestPage" refers to a class that's abstract thus cannot be instantiated. I think framework actually attempts to create an instance of it and fails but I might be wrong. Furthermore for the hierarchy of classes you might need to use x:Subclass as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xsubclass-directive

Comment: @Hamed Thanks for the reply. I, however, don't think I can use this, because from what I understand `x:Subclass` is a workaround for languages that do not support `partial` keyword. Furthermore, using `x:Subclass` would imply that I should use multiple XAML files (one for `TestPage1` and one for `TestPage2`, where each XAML then has the corresponding `x:Subclass` tag). This is exactly what I am trying to prevent. (after all, using multiple XAML files *does* work, but makes for a lot of exactly similar XAML code)

Comment: @Hamed Furthermore, I have now removed the constructor from the abstract class and instead added a constructor for `TestPage1` and `TestPage2` with `this.InitializeComponent()` in them. Sadly, to no avail.

Comment: @Leander The problem is not existence of a constructor. An abstract class cannot be instantiated. You cannot create an instance of an abstract class. Try it yourself using the 'new' keyword e.g var o = new MyAbstractClass(). this will fail regardless of existence of a constructor.

IMHO, your second sample works because the x:Class in them refer to a concrete (non-abstract) class.

Comment: @Leander As for the problem of reducing code duplication, in WPF we used to use the same page by replacing content of the page via Panels. With MVVM it was relatively easy and efficient too. I am not aware how it works with UWP but you might actually need only 1 page with 1 x:Class but multiple panels (or another form of content control) inside that page.

Comment: @Hamed Thanks for the clarification. I wonder however how it is possible that this does work in a Debug build, but not in a Release build. Since this seems like a problem that both builds should face... I think for now I will just copy the XAML, but it would be nice to find out why Debug is working, but Release not.

Comment: @Leander You're welcome. It is hard to tell since I don't have proper information of the innerworkings of the UWP Page class. That said, I just looked at the code you've shared and was wondering (in the Not Working class) is there any specific reason to have an "abstract" class? What happens if you remove that single keyword? The Page class is not abstract, is it?

Comment: @Hamed I have updated my MVCE, where I have removed the abstract keyword. Still this doesn't work, and would force me to only use virtual properties from now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226629/discussion-between-leander-and-hamed).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the way I want it to work does not seem to supported in a Release build, seemingly due to the way the .xaml and .cs files are compiled for a Release or Debug build.

For now I'm going to use multiple .xaml files, but I will keep trying to find a way to make this work and prevent a lot of exactly the same .xaml code (after all using multiple copies of the same code is asking for problems somewhere down the line).

I will update this answer accordingly when I do find an answer. (Thanks to Hamed and Mikah for the help so far)